# Running Micorweber from Docker images gives BusyBox errros

Tags: docker

I want to run specific version of Microweber. I found an image on Dockerhub. However, when I try to run it, it gives me strange errors:

`docker run -dp 80:80 karser/microweber:1.1.5`

And the logs, `docker logs d0fc362b6a86`:

```
Waiting for  to start
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

    -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
    -l  Listen mode, for inbound connects
    -lk With -e, provides persistent server
    -p PORT Local port
    -s ADDR Local address
    -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -n  Don't do DNS resolution
    -u  UDP mode
    -v  Verbose
    -o FILE Hex dump traffic
    -z  Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
```

Does it mean that something is wrong with my docker installation or with the image?